# Ordenar un select por categorias y subcategorias php

Tags: php

Buen dia amigos.

tengo un select el cual quisiera mostrar por orden de padre e hijo quedando de la siguiente manera
Cuando desligue el select

```
Categoría 1 
-subcategoría 1
--subcategoría 1
-subcategoría 2 
--subcategoría 2
Categoría 2 
-subcategoría 1
--subcategoría 1
-subcategoría 2 
--subcategoría 2
```

El codigo que tengo hasta ahora muestra la lista pero no esta en orden

Esta es la tabla

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categoria`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categoria` (
  `idcategoria` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text NOT NULL,
  `portada` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `datecreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `categoria_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcategoria`),
  KEY `categoria_id` (`categoria_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

este es el modal

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="listCategoria">Categoría <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" data-live-search="true" id="listCategoria" name="listCategoria" required=""></select>
</div>
```

este es mi CategoriasModal.php en el cual realizo la consulta

```
        public function selectCategorias()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categoria 
                    WHERE status != 0 ";
            $request = $this->select_all($sql);
            return $request;
        }
```

esta es la función

```
        public function getSelectCategorias(){
            $htmlOptions = "";
            $arrData = $this->model->selectCategorias();
            if(count($arrData) > 0 ){
                for ($i=0; $i < count($arrData); $i++) { 
                    if($arrData[$i]['status'] == 1 ){
                    $htmlOptions .= '<option value="'.$arrData[$i]['idcategoria'].'">'.$arrData[$i]['nombre'].'</option>';
                    }
                }
            }
            echo $htmlOptions;
            die();  
        }
```

y esta el funtions.js

```
function fntCategorias(){
    if(document.querySelector('#listCategoria')){
        let ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Categorias/getSelectCategorias';
        let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? 
                    new XMLHttpRequest() : 
                    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        request.open("GET",ajaxUrl,true);
        request.send();
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                document.querySelector('#listCategoria').innerHTML = request.responseText;
                $('#listCategoria').selectpicker('render');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

agradezco mucho la colaboración para poder lograr que muestre el select ordenado

---

Triby gracias por la pronta repuesta

Aquí te coloco mis 3 archivos

este es el controlador categorias.php

```
<?php 
   class Categorias extends Controllers{

       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           session_start();
           session_regenerate_id(true);
           if(empty($_SESSION['login']))
           {
               header('Location: '.base_url().'/login');
           }
           getPermisos(6);
       }

       public function Categorias()
       {
           if(empty($_SESSION['permisosMod']['r'])){
               header("Location:".base_url().'/dashboard');
           }
           $data['page_id'] = 6;
           $data['page_menu'] = 4;
           $data['page_tag'] = "Categorias";
           $data['page_tag2'] = "Lista de Categorias";
           $data['page_title'] = "CATEGORIAS";
           $data['page_title2'] = "LISTA DE CATEGORIAS";
           $data['page_name'] = "categorias";
           $data['page_functions_js'] = "functions_categorias.js";
       
           $this->views->getView($this,"categorias",$data);
       }


       public function setCategoria(){
           if($_POST){
               if (empty($_POST['txtNombre']) || empty($_POST['txtDescripcion']) || empty($_POST['listStatus'])) 
               {
                   $arrResponse = array("status" => false, "msg" => 'Datos incorrectos.');
               } else {
   
                   $intIdcategoria = intval($_POST['idCategoria']);
                   $strCategoria =  strClean($_POST['txtNombre']);
                   $strDescipcion = strClean($_POST['txtDescripcion']);
                   $intStatus = intval($_POST['listStatus']);
                   $intCategoriaid = intval($_POST['listCategoria']);
   
                   $foto           = $_FILES['foto'];
                   $nombre_foto    = $foto['name'];
                   $type           = $foto['type'];
                   $url_temp       = $foto['tmp_name'];
                   $imgPortada     = 'portada_categoria.png';
                   $request_cateria = "";
                   if ($nombre_foto != '') {
                       $imgPortada = 'img_' . md5(date('d-m-Y H:m:s')) . '.jpg';
                   }
   
                   if($intIdcategoria == 0)
                   {
                       //Crear
                       if($_SESSION['permisosMod']['w']){
                           $request_cateria = $this->model->inserCategoria($strCategoria, $strDescipcion,$imgPortada,$intStatus,$intCategoriaid);
                           $option = 1;
                       }
                   }else{
                       //Actualizar
                       if($_SESSION['permisosMod']['u']){
                           if($nombre_foto == ''){
                               if($_POST['foto_actual'] != 'portada_categoria.png' && $_POST['foto_remove'] == 0 ){
                                   $imgPortada = $_POST['foto_actual'];
                               }
                           }
                           $request_cateria = $this->model->updateCategoria($intIdcategoria,$strCategoria, $strDescipcion,$imgPortada,$intStatus,$intCategoriaid);
                           $option = 2;
                       }
                   }
                   if ($request_cateria > 0) {
                       if ($option == 1) {
                           $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Datos guardados correctamente.');
                           if ($nombre_foto != '') {
                               uploadImage($foto, $imgPortada);
                           }
                       } else {
                           $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Datos actualizados correctamente.');
                           if ($nombre_foto != '') {
                               uploadImage($foto, $imgPortada);
                           }
   
                           if (($nombre_foto == '' && $_POST['foto_remove'] == 1 && $_POST['foto_actual'] != 'portada_categoria.png')
                               || ($nombre_foto != '' && $_POST['foto_actual'] != 'portada_categoria.png')
                           ) {
                               deleteFile($_POST['foto_actual']);
                           }
                       }
                   } else if ($request_cateria == 'exist') {
                       $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => '¡Atención! La categoría ya existe.');
                   } else {
                       $arrResponse = array("status" => false, "msg" => 'No es posible almacenar los datos.');
                   }
               }
               echo json_encode($arrResponse, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
           }
           die();
           }

       public function getCategorias()
       {
           if($_SESSION['permisosMod']['r']){
               $arrData = $this->model->selectCategorias();
               for ($i=0; $i < count($arrData); $i++) {
                   $btnView = '';
                   $btnEdit = '';
                   $btnDelete = '';

                   if($arrData[$i]['status'] == 1)
                   {
                       $arrData[$i]['status'] = '<span class="badge badge-success">Activo</span>';
                   }else{
                       $arrData[$i]['status'] = '<span class="badge badge-danger">Inactivo</span>';
                   }

                   if($_SESSION['permisosMod']['r']){
                       $btnView = '<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick="fntViewInfo('.$arrData[$i]['idcategoria'].')" title="Ver categoría"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></button>';
                   }
                   if($_SESSION['permisosMod']['u']){
                       $btnEdit = '<button class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm" onClick="fntEditInfo(this,'.$arrData[$i]['idcategoria'].')" title="Editar categoría"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>';
                   }
                   if($_SESSION['permisosMod']['d']){  
                       $btnDelete = '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick="fntDelInfo('.$arrData[$i]['idcategoria'].')" title="Eliminar categoría"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>';
                   }
                   $arrData[$i]['options'] = '<div class="text-center">'.$btnView.' '.$btnEdit.' '.$btnDelete.'</div>';
               }
               echo json_encode($arrData,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
           }
           die();
       }



       public function getCategoria($idcategoria)
       {
           if($_SESSION['permisosMod']['r']){
               $intIdcategoria = intval($idcategoria);
               if($intIdcategoria > 0)
               {
                   $arrData = $this->model->selectCategoria($intIdcategoria);
                   if(empty($arrData))
                   {
                       $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'Datos no encontrados.');
                   }else{
                       $arrData['url_portada'] = media().'/images/uploads/'.$arrData['portada'];
                       $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'data' => $arrData);
                   }
                   echo json_encode($arrResponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
               }
           }
           die();
       }

       public function delCategoria()
       {
           if($_POST){
               if($_SESSION['permisosMod']['d']){
                   $intIdcategoria = intval($_POST['idCategoria']);
                   $requestDelete = $this->model->deleteCategoria($intIdcategoria);
                   if($requestDelete == 'ok')
                   {
                       $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Se ha eliminado la categoría');
                   }else if($requestDelete == 'exist'){
                       $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'No es posible eliminar una categoría con productos asociados.');
                   }else{
                       $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'Error al eliminar la categoría.');
                   }
                   echo json_encode($arrResponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
               }
           }
           die();
       }


           /**
    * Función recursiva para agrupar categorías / subcategorías, subsub...
    * @param int $padre    Iniciar con los hijos de esta categoría
    * @param int $nivel    Sirve para agregar prefijo a subcategorías: -, --, ---
    * @returns string
    */

       public function optionsCategorias($padre, $nivel) {
       // Inicializar salida
       $ret = '';
       // Crear prefijo para indentar subcategorías
       $prefijo = ($nivel == 0) ? '' : str_pad('', $nivel, '-') . ' ';
       // Recorrer categorías en el padre para mostrar
       foreach($this->categorias[$padre] as $id) {
           // Generar option
           $ret .= "<option value=\"$id\">$prefijo{$this->categorias['todas'][$id]['nombre']}</option>";
           // ¿La categoría tiene hijos?
           if(isset($this->categorias[$id])) {
               // Agregar opciones para cada hijo
               $ret .= $this->optionsCategorias($id, $nivel + 1);
           }
       }
       return $ret;
   }




   public function getSelectCategorias() {
       // Inicializar arreglo
       // Para evitar inconsistencias, deberías definir la propiedad en la clase
       $categorias ="";
       $arrData = $this->model->selectCategorias();
       $this->categorias = ['todas' => []];
       // Recorrer para armar arreglo
       foreach($arrData as $cat) {
           // Insertar arreglo en "todas" con ID como índice
           $this->$categorias['todas'][$cat['idcategoria']] = $cat;
           // Forzar a que sea entero
           $padre = intval($cat['categoria_id']);
           // Verificar que existe el arreglo de hijos
           if(!isset($this->$categorias[$padre])) {
               $this->$categorias[$padre] = [];
           }
           // Agregar como hijo
           $this->$categorias[$padre][] = $cat['idcategoria'];
       }
       // Iniciar con categorías principales
          dep($this);
           exit;
       echo $this->optionsCategorias(0, 0);
       die();  
   }


}





?>
```

este es el model CategoriasModel.php

```
<?php 

    class CategoriasModel extends Mysql
    {
        public $intIdcategoria;
        public $strCategoria;
        public $strDescripcion;
        public $intStatus;
        public $strPortada;
        public $intCategoriaid;
        private $categorias = [];

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function inserCategoria(string $nombre, string $descripcion, string $portada, int $status, int $categoria_id){

            $return = 0;
            $this->strCategoria = $nombre;
            $this->strDescripcion = $descripcion;
            $this->strPortada = $portada;
            $this->intStatus = $status;
            $this->intCategoriaid = $categoria_id;

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE nombre = '{$this->strCategoria}' ";
            $request = $this->select_all($sql);

            if(empty($request))
            {
                $query_insert  = "INSERT INTO categoria(nombre,descripcion,portada,status,categoria_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
                $arrData = array($this->strCategoria, 
                                 $this->strDescripcion, 
                                 $this->strPortada, 
                                 $this->intStatus, 
                                 $this->intCategoriaid);
                $request_insert = $this->insert($query_insert,$arrData);
                $return = $request_insert;
            }else{
                $return = "exist";
            }
            return $return;
        }

        public function selectCategorias()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categoria 
                    WHERE status != 0 ";
            $request = $this->select_all($sql);
            return $request;
        }

        public function selectCategoria(int $idcategoria){
            $this->intIdcategoria = $idcategoria;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categoria
                    WHERE idcategoria = $this->intIdcategoria";
            $request = $this->select($sql);
            return $request;
        }

        public function updateCategoria(int $idcategoria, string $categoria, string $descripcion, string $portada, int $status, int $categoria_id ){
            $this->intIdcategoria = $idcategoria;
            $this->strCategoria = $categoria;
            $this->strDescripcion = $descripcion;
            $this->strPortada = $portada;
            $this->intStatus = $status;
            $this->intCategoriaid = $categoria_id;

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE nombre = '{$this->strCategoria}' AND idcategoria != $this->intIdcategoria";
            $request = $this->select_all($sql);

            if(empty($request))
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE categoria SET nombre = ?, descripcion = ?, portada = ?, status = ?, categoria_id = ?  WHERE idcategoria = $this->intIdcategoria ";
                $arrData = array($this->strCategoria, 
                                 $this->strDescripcion, 
                                 $this->strPortada, 
                                 $this->intStatus, 
                                 $this->intCategoriaid);
                $request = $this->update($sql,$arrData);
            }else{
                $request = "exist";
            }
            return $request;            
        }

        public function deleteCategoria(int $idcategoria)
        {
            $this->intIdcategoria = $idcategoria;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE categoriaid = $this->intIdcategoria";
            $request = $this->select_all($sql);
            if(empty($request))
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE categoria SET status = ? WHERE idcategoria = $this->intIdcategoria ";
                $arrData = array(0);
                $request = $this->update($sql,$arrData);
                if($request)
                {
                    $request = 'ok';    
                }else{
                    $request = 'error';
                }
            }else{
                $request = 'exist';
            }
            return $request;
        }   



    }
 ?>
```

y este el fuctions_categorias.js

```
let tableCategorias;
let rowTable = "";
let divLoading = document.querySelector("#divLoading");


    tableCategorias = $('#tableCategorias').dataTable( {

            dom: '<"row"<"col-md-12"<"row"<"col-md-6"B><"col-md-6"f> > ><"col-md-12"rt> <"col-md-12"<"row"<"col-md-5"i><"col-md-7"p>>> >',
            buttons: {
                buttons: [
                    { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn' },
                    { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn' },
                    { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn' },
                    { extend: 'print', className: 'btn' }
                ]
            },

            "aProcessing":true,
            "aServerSide":true,
            "oLanguage": {
                "oPaginate": { "sPrevious": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-left"><line x1="19" y1="12" x2="5" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 19 5 12 12 5"></polyline></svg>', "sNext": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-right"><line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 5 19 12 12 19"></polyline></svg>' },
                "sInfo": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
                "sSearch": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-search"><circle cx="11" cy="11" r="8"></circle><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="16.65" y2="16.65"></line></svg>',
                "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search...",
               "sLengthMenu": "Results :  _MENU_",
            },
            "ajax":{
                "url": " "+base_url+"/Categorias/getCategorias",
                "dataSrc":""
            },
            "columns":[
                {"data":"idcategoria"},
                {"data":"nombre"},
                {"data":"descripcion"},
                {"data":"status"},
                {"data":"options"}
            ],
            "resonsieve":"true",
            "bDestroy": true,
            "stripeClasses": [],
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "lengthMenu": [7, 10, 20, 50],
            "order":[[0,"desc"]]
            });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    if(document.querySelector("#foto")){
        let foto = document.querySelector("#foto");
        foto.onchange = function(e) {
            let uploadFoto = document.querySelector("#foto").value;
            let fileimg = document.querySelector("#foto").files;
            let nav = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            let contactAlert = document.querySelector('#form_alert');
            if(uploadFoto !=''){
                let type = fileimg[0].type;
                let name = fileimg[0].name;
                if(type != 'image/jpeg' && type != 'image/jpg' && type != 'image/png'){
                    contactAlert.innerHTML = '<p class="errorArchivo">El archivo no es válido.</p>';
                    if(document.querySelector('#img')){
                        document.querySelector('#img').remove();
                    }
                    document.querySelector('.delPhoto').classList.add("notBlock");
                    foto.value="";
                    return false;
                }else{  
                        contactAlert.innerHTML='';
                        if(document.querySelector('#img')){
                            document.querySelector('#img').remove();
                        }
                        document.querySelector('.delPhoto').classList.remove("notBlock");
                        let objeto_url = nav.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
                        document.querySelector('.prevPhoto div').innerHTML = "<img id='img' src="+objeto_url+">";
                    }
            }else{
                alert("No selecciono foto");
                if(document.querySelector('#img')){
                    document.querySelector('#img').remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(document.querySelector(".delPhoto")){
        let delPhoto = document.querySelector(".delPhoto");
        delPhoto.onclick = function(e) {
            document.querySelector("#foto_remove").value= 1;
            removePhoto();
        }
    }

        //Nueva Categoria
    let formCategoria = document.querySelector("#formCategoria");
    formCategoria.onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let strNombre = document.querySelector('#txtNombre').value;
        let strDescripcion = document.querySelector('#txtDescripcion').value;
        let intStatus = document.querySelector('#listStatus').value;        
        let intCategoriaid = document.querySelector('#listCategoria').value;
        if(strNombre == '' || strDescripcion == '' || intStatus == '')
        {
            swal("Atención", "Todos los campos son obligatorios." , "error");
            return false;
        }
/*        divLoading.style.display = "flex";*/
        let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        let ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Categorias/setCategoria'; 
        let formData = new FormData(formCategoria);
        request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
        request.send(formData);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
           if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                
                let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                if(objData.status)
                {
                    if(rowTable == ""){
                        tableCategorias.api().ajax.reload();
                    }else{
                        htmlStatus = intStatus == 1 ? 
                            '<span class="badge badge-success">Activo</span>' : 
                            '<span class="badge badge-danger">Inactivo</span>';
                        rowTable.cells[1].textContent = strNombre;
                        rowTable.cells[2].textContent = strDescripcion;
                        rowTable.cells[3].innerHTML = htmlStatus;
                        rowTable = "";
                    }

                    $('#modalFormCategorias').modal("hide");
                    formCategoria.reset();
                    swal("Categoria", objData.msg ,"success");
                    removePhoto();
                }else{
                    swal("Error", objData.msg , "error");
                }              
            } 
/*            divLoading.style.display = "none";*/
            return false;
        }
    }

        fntCategorias();

}, false);

function fntViewInfo(idcategoria){
    let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    let ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Categorias/getCategoria/'+idcategoria;
    request.open("GET",ajaxUrl,true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            if(objData.status)
            {
                let estado = objData.data.status == 1 ? 
                '<span class="badge badge-success">Habilitado</span>' : 
                '<span class="badge badge-danger">Deshabilitado</span>';
                document.querySelector("#celId").value = objData.data.idcategoria;
                document.querySelector("#celNombre").value = objData.data.nombre;
                document.querySelector("#celDescripcion").value = objData.data.descripcion;
                document.querySelector("#celEstado").innerHTML = estado;
                document.querySelector("#imgCategoria").innerHTML = '<img src="'+objData.data.url_portada+'"></img>';
                $('#modalViewCategoria').modal('show');
            }else{
                swal("Error", objData.msg , "error");
            }
        }
    }
}

function fntEditInfo(element,idcategoria){
    rowTable = element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    document.querySelector('#titleModal').innerHTML ="Actualizar Categoría";
    document.querySelector('#btnText').innerHTML ="Actualizar";


    let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    let ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Categorias/getCategoria/'+idcategoria;
    request.open("GET",ajaxUrl,true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            if(objData.status)
            {
                document.querySelector("#idCategoria").value = objData.data.idcategoria;
                document.querySelector("#txtNombre").value = objData.data.nombre;
                document.querySelector("#txtDescripcion").value = objData.data.descripcion;
                document.querySelector('#foto_actual').value = objData.data.portada;
                document.querySelector("#foto_remove").value= 0;
                document.querySelector("#listCategoria").value = objData.data.categoria_id;
                $('#listCategoria').selectpicker('render');

                if(objData.data.status == 1){
                    document.querySelector("#listStatus").value = 1;
                }else{
                    document.querySelector("#listStatus").value = 2;
                }
                $('#listStatus').selectpicker('render');

                if(document.querySelector('#img')){
                    document.querySelector('#img').src = objData.data.url_portada;
                }else{
                    document.querySelector('.prevPhoto div').innerHTML = "<img id='img' src="+objData.data.url_portada+">";
                }

                if(objData.data.portada == 'portada_categoria.png'){
                    document.querySelector('.delPhoto').classList.add("notBlock");
                }else{
                    document.querySelector('.delPhoto').classList.remove("notBlock");
                }
                
                $('#modalFormCategorias').modal('show');

            }else{
                swal("Error", objData.msg , "error");
            }
        }
    }
}

function fntDelInfo(idcategoria){
    swal({
        title: "Eliminar Categoría",
        text: "¿Realmente quieres eliminar la categoría?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Si, ¡Eliminar!",
        cancelButtonText: "No, ¡Cancelar!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: true
            })
            .then(resultado => {
                if (resultado.value) {
                    let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                    let ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Categorias/delCategoria';
                    let strData = "idCategoria="+idcategoria;
                    request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    request.send(strData);
                    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                            let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                            if(objData.status)
                            {
                                swal("Eliminar!", objData.msg , "success");
                                tableCategorias.api().ajax.reload();
                            }else{
                                swal("Atención!", objData.msg , "error");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

    });

}



function fntCategorias(){
    if($('#listCategoria').length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + '/Categorias/getSelectCategorias',
            dataType: 'html', // Tipo de dato esperado
            method: 'GET',    // Por defecto es GET, pero puedes especificar POST u otro
           // Función que recibe resultados
           success: function(data) {
               // Asignar HTML obtenido
               $('#listCategoria').html(data);
               // Activar selectPicker
               $('#listCategoria').selectpicker('render');
           },
           // Si hubo algún error se ejecuta esta función
           error: function(xhr, status, error) {
               console.log(`Error en petición AJAX, estado: ${status}, mensaje: ${error}`);
           }
        });
    }
}

function removePhoto(){
    document.querySelector('#foto').value ="";
    document.querySelector('.delPhoto').classList.add("notBlock");
    if(document.querySelector('#img')){
        document.querySelector('#img').remove();
    }
}


function openModal()
{
    rowTable = "";
    document.querySelector('#idCategoria').value ="";
    document.querySelector('#btnText').innerHTML ="Guardar";
    document.querySelector('#titleModal').innerHTML = "Nueva categoría";
    document.querySelector("#formCategoria").reset();
    $('#listCategoria').selectpicker('render');
    $('#modalFormCategorias').modal('show');
    removePhoto();
}
```

Comment: La propiedad `categorias` aparece como arreglo vacío y, debajo, tienes el arreglo real, pero sin índice, por eso obtienes el error. ¿Dónde y cómo defines categorías?

Comment: Tengo la consulta a la base de datos de alli paso a la que tu me colocaste que era parecida a la mia que es `public function getSelectCategorias()` lo unico que agregue de mas fue la variable `$categorias = "";` ya que me indicaba que no estaba definida. de resto debe ser alli en el getselect que es esta la falla verdad ?

Comment: Debes definir categorías como propiedad de la clase, ejemplo: `class miClase { private $categorias = []; /* resto de propiedades y métodos */ }`

Comment: Triby de verdad disculpa tata molestia agregue el private pero en mis CategoriasModel. te coloque mis 3 archivos los cuales estoy trabajando pero nada que sale dentro del array no entiendo porque lo coloca afuera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he encontrado la forma de lograr una agrupación de este tipo mediante una consulta a base de datos y, por lo general, acostumbro crear un arreglo para almacenar las categorías e identificar sus subcategorías (hijos), algo como:

```
$categorias = [
    'todas' => [
        1 => ['nombre' => 'Categoría 1', 'padre' => 0],
        2 => ['nombre' => 'Subcategoría 1', 'padre' => 1],
        3 => ['nombre' => 'Categoría 2', 'padre' => 0],
        4 => ['nombre' => 'Subcategoría 2', 'padre' => 3],
        5 => ['nombre' => 'Subsubcategoría 1', 'padre' => 4]
    ],
    0 => [1, 3], // Categorías principales
    1 => [2],    // Subcategorías de "Categoría 1"
    3 => [4],    // Subcategorías de "Categoría 2"
    4 => [5]     // Subcategorías de "Subcategoría 2"
];
```

Esto permite tener múltiples niveles y mostrar de forma sencilla, mediante una función recursiva, comenzando con el índice cero:

```
    /**
     * Función recursiva para agrupar categorías / subcategorías, subsub...
     * @param int $padre    Iniciar con los hijos de esta categoría
     * @param int $nivel    Sirve para agregar prefijo a subcategorías: -, --, ---
     * @returns string
     */
    public function optionsCategorias($padre, $nivel) {
        // Inicializar salida
        $ret = '';
        // Crear prefijo para indentar subcategorías
        $prefijo = ($nivel == 0) ? '' : str_pad('', $nivel, '-') . ' ';
        // Recorrer categorías en el padre para mostrar
        foreach($this->categorias[$padre] as $id) {
            // Generar option
            $ret .= "<option value=\"$id\">$prefijo{$this->categorias['todas'][$id]['nombre']}</option>";
            // ¿La categoría tiene hijos?
            if(isset($this->categorias[$id])) {
                // Agregar opciones para cada hijo
                $ret .= $this->optionsCategorias($id, $nivel + 1);
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    public function getSelectCategorias() {
        // Inicializar arreglo
        // Para evitar inconsistencias, deberías definir la propiedad en la clase
        $this->categorias = ['todas' => []];
        $arrData = $this->model->selectCategorias();
        // Recorrer para armar arreglo
        foreach($arrData as $cat) {
            // Insertar arreglo en "todas" con ID como índice
            $this->categorias['todas'][$cat['idcategoria']] = $cat;

            // Forzar a que sea entero
            $padre = intval($cat['categoria_id']);

            // Verificar que existe el arreglo de hijos
            if(!isset($this->categorias[$padre])) {
                $this->categorias[$padre] = [];
            }
            // Agregar como hijo
            $this->categorias[$padre][] = $cat['idcategoria'];
        }
        // Iniciar con categorías principales
        echo $this->optionsCategorias(0, 0);
        die();  
    }
```

Con el ejemplo inicial vas a obtener las opciones así:

```
Categoría 1
- Subcategoría 1
Categoría 2
- Subcategoría 2
-- Subsubcategoría 1
```

Adicionalmente, ya que estás usando *jQuery* deberías aprovechar las facilidades que te da para acceder a elementos y ejecutar [peticiones AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
function fntCategorias(){
    if($('#listCategoria').length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + '/Categorias/getSelectCategorias',
            dataType: 'html', // Tipo de dato esperado
            method: 'GET',    // Por defecto es GET, pero puedes especificar POST u otro
           // Función que recibe resultados
           success: function(data) {
               // Asignar HTML obtenido
               $('#listCategoria').html(data);
               // Activar selectPicker
               $('#listCategoria').selectpicker('render');
           },
           // Si hubo algún error se ejecuta esta función
           error: function(xhr, status, error) {
               console.log(`Error en petición AJAX, estado: ${status}, mensaje: ${error}`);
           }
        });
    }
}
```

**Importante:** No copies y pegues el código, porque no tengo forma de probarlo y podría tener errores. Trata de entender lo que hace y, solo entonces, adáptalo a tus necesidades. No dudes en preguntar si algo no quedó claro.

Comment: Triby de verdad agradecido excelente tu ayuda

de verdad se muy poco de programación ando aprendiendo 

estoy ejecutando parte del codigo y en function optionsCategorias
 me da el siguiente error

 `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in \Categorias.php on line 192`

seria esta linea `foreach($this->categorias[$padre] as $id) {`

Comment: @Brian, ya vi el problema. La columna `categoria_id` puede tener valor nulo para las categorías principales. Edité la respuesta para forzar a que sea un entero con `$padre = intval($cat['categoria_id']);`. Cuando sea nulo, lo va a tomar como cero.

Comment: Modifique y me sigue dando el mismo fallo. actualice la publicación y te coloque el resultado del dep($this); en el public function getSelectCategorias gracias nuevamente

Comment: Por eso decía lo de no copiar y pegar, sino primero entender. Resulta que hay varios `$this->$categorias`... ¿Ves que sobra un `$`? Ese es el error; actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Triby Excelente men eres un grande muchas gracias!